Overriding Bootstrap 5.3 styles using scss in Blazor WebApp
What I exactly want to do now is to override primary color, but I'm not sure if it's even possible in Blazor. Bootstrap that comes with Blazor does not have any scss files which are apparently required for override. Installing Bootstrap through nuget gives you exactly the same files.
So for example this code, which according to the internet will override the primary color (as long as you compile it to css), does nothing when used in Blazor.
$primary: #080808;
@import 'lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';


It seems like your problem is not related to Blazor. You want to customize Bootstrap primary color. Am I correct?

@FarzadM. It is related to Blazor, since Blazor is using css version of Bootstrap. It wouldn't be a problem in framework that references scss version of Bootstrap.

Blazor is not related to Bootstrap in any ways. Official Blazor templates use bootstrap, but it is for demonstration purposes only. You can remove it instantly and use your own preferred styling method. If you want to customize Bootstrap colors and use it in your Blazor project, I can help you to do that.
